# Uninstall VM Workstation 9.0 in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-workstation

I can't uninstall VM from my PC. I run from the command line

```
sudo vmware-installer --uninstall-product vmware-workstation
```

but the installer shows me this message

```
vmware installer could not shut down all running virtual machines. if you have ACE VMs open, please shut them down or suspend them now and press
```

I don't have any VMachines open...

Thanks!

Comment: if I try sudo service vmware stop


Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                     done
At least one instance of VMware VMX is still running.
Please stop all running instances of VMware VMX first.
 
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done